# Best OOP practice for grandchild class calling methods from its parent

Tags: c#, oop

I would like to know the best practice to structure classes in order to call parent methods when the class has a grandparent.

Let's say I have this scenario:

```
public class Vehicle { // parent

    public bool moves;
    public bool flies;
    public float maxSpeed;

    public virtual void Initialize () {
        moves = true;
    }
}

public class Airplane : Vehicle { // child
    public override void Initialize () {
        base.Initialize ();
        flies = true;
    }
}

public class Jet : Airplane { // grandchild
    public override void Initialize () {
        base.Initialize ();
        maxSpeed = 400f;
    }
}
```

Now, if I instantiate a Jet object, it will run the Vehicle initialization, **but not the Airplane parent code** (meaning it will not fly).

There are a few workarounds for this. One is moving the Airplane code to every child class, but then it defeats the purpose of using OOP. What would be the best practice to solve this problem?

**Note**: I cannot use constructors, because this is an Unity3D application, and all classes attached to a GameObject should inherit from the MonoBehaviour class, and it has its own initialization functions like Awake() and Start(), and does **not** allow constructors.

Comment: What is a constructor?

Comment: @EdPlunkett You can learn more about constuctors here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors  :p

Comment: @RufusL If only there were some resource on the web that could answer questions like that automatically.

Comment: It would be nice if this code were written in a way that it was compilable without having to manually edit it.

Comment: Nothing in the code makes sense. Why is an initialize method used instead of a constructor? Why are the initializers private? Why are they not virtual?  Why do you believe that the Jet object will not call the base method?  Why are field initializers not **field initializers**? I can't make heads nor tails of this question.

Comment: While it is true that a constructor would be the way to go, it's also possible that he may not want to initialize the class upon creation for some reason, so I would not be so quick to mock without knowing all the details.

Comment: Your premise of  "Now, if I instantiate a `Jet` object" is faulty, because none of the code presented will even compile.

Comment: @EricLippert I guess the constructor from Vehicle calls Initialize method. But its is esoteric because we did not see that constructor code ;o)

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet The downvotes are for fake, not compilable and missing essential parts code

Comment: It was written by memory, it's almost pseudo code. Tried to make it as small as possible to make you see the main point here. Sorry if the code does not compile.

Comment: It does not use constructors because it runs on Unity3D, and the main class inherits from Monobehaviour, and it does not allow using constructors. You have to use Awake() and Start() there, which causes the problem I showed. Sorry for not mentioning it. I can't solve it with constructors.

Comment: We don't see the main point *because you have omitted all the details necessary to understanding the problem*. By posting code that doesn't compile, we think that the problem is that you're making typos; a surprisingly large number of problems posted on SO are just typos from beginners who cannot spot them.

Comment: The problem is not just that it doesn't compile, but even after making it compile (and creating constructors that call `Initialize`), it doesn't demonstrate the behavior you're describing.

Comment: The code has now been updated to legal C# code but **does not demonstrate the problem described.** When Jet.Initialize is executed, the airplane and vehicle initializers are executed as expected. Once again I have no idea what this question is asking. **Show us a program that reproduces the problem**.

Comment: Regardless of that: the class design is getting worse as we go on. Why are the fields public? Why aren't they *virtual properties*?  If we have `class V { public virtual bool Flies { get { return false; } } class A : V { public override bool Flies { get { return true; } } class J : A { }` then we're done; no initialize method is needed.

Comment: The fields are here only to be placeholders of the behaviours of the methods, which I didn't bring because I thought of making it as simple as possible to focus on the actual problem. My goal is to clarify the OO issue, not to debug that little snippet. If you are telling me that on your C# compiler, both Vehicle and Airplane methods are being called when you call the Initialize from Jet, than it tells my the Unity3D implementation of C# is different from Microsoft's. My conclusion is that it is a Unity3D bug, and I will report it to them. Thanks.

Comment: @Flight: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/  Select isn't broken. You should have *ironclad* certainty that you have not made a typo somewhere before you report this as a bug. I would be very, very surprised if this was a compiler bug.

Answer (score 8):

> I would like to know the best practice to structure classes in order to call parent methods when the class has a grandparent.

**You do not do this**.

The supposition of the question is that *the Jet which derives from Airplane needs to know the implementation detail that Airplane is derived from Vehicle*.  That's a bad supposition. The best practice is to treat Airplane as a black box (no pun intended), without taking advantage of knowledge of its implementation details.

Your Initialize method has a *contract*: it initializes something. If you want it called, you call it.  It is responsible for ensuring that its invariants are met; let it do its work.

Now, in this *specific* case you don't do *any* of this.  You don't write an initialize method, and you certainly don't call the base.  If you want field initializers then *you write field initializers*.

```
class Vehicle { protected bool moves = true; }
class Airplane : Vehicle { protected bool flies = true; }
class Jet : Airplane { protected double speed = 400; }
```

Let's consider a better example. Suppose we have a display surface which can be redrawn:

```
interface IUserInterface { void Redraw(); }
```

Now we can come up with a hierarchy where the rule is: when you are redrawn, you have to also call your superclass:

```
abstract class ControlWithChildren : IUserInterface
{
  ...
  protected IEnumerable<IUserInterface> children;
  public virtual void Redraw() { 
    foreach(var child in children) child.Redraw();
}

class Panel : ControlWithChildren
{
  ...
  public override void Redraw()
  {
    ... redraw panel elements ...
    base.Redraw();
  }
}

class PanelWithTitle : Panel
{
  ...
  public override void Redraw()
  {
    ... redraw title element ...
    base.Redraw();
  }
}
```

And there you go. PanelWithTitle just deals with redrawing the title, and defers the rest of the work to Panel.  Panel redraws the panel background, and defers the rest of the work to ControlWithChildren.  **PanelWithTitle needs to know nothing about ControlWithChildren's redraw semantics**.  If it does need to know that, then something is wrong with the implementation of *Panel*.

Comment: I think you misread his question. He's asking how to call a `parent` method. The problem stated is that the parent method is being skipped and the grandparent is being called. At least that's what I think he said.

Comment: @RufusL: Sure, he says that, with no evidence and no code which compiles or runs. The question is: what's the best practice for calling a base method in a world where there is a grand-base, and **that question indicates a possible bad mindset about the relationship between a class and its grandbase**.  The more important thing here is not that the OP fix their typo in the not-shown broken code. The most important thing is that they start thinking correctly about type hierarchies.

Answer (score -2):

I would create interfaces and stay away from inheritance. Use composition instead. In other words, make Jet contain both the Airplane and Vehicle classes (I'm assuming a Jet has special abilities or properties that Airplane does not). And use delegator methods.

It makes your project less brittle. In other words, if you change your base class, you have to worry about how all your child (and maybe even great grandchildren) handle it. If you contain it, though, as long as the interface is the same, the container classes will not care.

This is not defeating the purpose of OOP, but a better way of using it. We still have those separate objects and are not copy-pasting code. We are, however, defeating the use of inheritance.

I recommend you read this Star-Wars themed entertaining blog article.
* http://blog.berniesumption.com/software/inheritance-is-evil-and-must-be-destroyed/

If that's not your thing just Google "composition over inheritance" and enjoy the flame wars.

Comment: An airplane contains a vehicle? So is this a cargo plane?

Comment: "I'm assuming a Jet has special abilities or properties that Airplane does not". It has a jet engine.

Comment: You don't understand the concept of composition.   You use composition when modeling  a *has a* relationship, not a *is a* relationship.  Additionally you don't just throw away inheritance, you use it *with* composition. An airplane is a vehicle, a jet is an airplane.    In a properly composed class, you would *still* have vehicle and airplane, but airplane simply defines a composition of parts that make it, so a jet would simply *swap out* pieces of composition.  But if jet had more functionality than an airplane you would need to make a new class.  The guy in your link even shows this.